# How to link Team Services account with Azure with new console

Tags: azure, azure-devops

This was quite easy with the old console. Now its baffling. How do I achieve this feat?

Answer (score 0):

Answer [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs).

I browsed for "Team services". The panel that comes up lists the Team Services accounts that you have access to. And then you can link a subscription to them.